# C# lambda expression reverse direction <=

Tags: c#, lambda, operators

I have seen some code which uses the `<=` operator. Can you explain what is the use of having lambda in reverse direction?

Comment: I'll admit... I did laught at this one...

Comment: Now, be honest. You're kidding, aren't you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028

Comment: Having looking at 1000 lines of code,I got confused.sorry guys.

Comment: This is a quality question! Made my day.

Comment: no it isn't, it's a low quality question, but because it's 'funny' it's allowed to be kept?

Comment: Easy to answer != Low Quality. I'm not sure what is with the compulsion to close everything. Every developer has moments where they need to search something that should be obvious... Why not allow an actual answer instead of the first three pages of search results being "Google It".

Comment: OP built a significant part of his reputation on this question. He's my hero! Give your votes and honor your breaks! :-)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

That's just less than or equal.  I don't think C# lambdas work like that.  It's too early in the morning.  You need coffee.

Answer (score 43):

That's not a lambda at all. That's *less than or equal to*

<sub>*[(Except when it's actually a reverse lambda)](https://gist.github.com/3251441)*</sub>

Answer (score 15):

It is only used as 'less than or equal to' operation, as in:

```cs
if (i <= 5) {
    // ...
}
```