# Use of =+ operator in Java?

Tags: java, operators

I've the following code:

```
public class Operators {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =+ 2;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Upon executing I'm getting the following output: **2**

So what does **`=+`** operator actually does here?

**EDIT:**

As some answered, it is assigning `+2` to `i`, consider the following code:

```
public class Operators {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i =- -2;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

So in above case, output should be **`-2`**. But I'm getting **`2`**

So I suppose, it is `-(-2)`, which gives `2`. *Right*?

Comment: `=+` is two operator `=` and prefix `+` one single.

Comment: It would probably make better sense if it was written as `i = +2`, which is the same as `i = 2`.  But if I said `i = -2` I think it would make more sense...

Comment: Do you know Javascript? read [What does = +_ mean in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137/what-does-mean-in-javascript) `=+` is interesting in JavaScript.

Comment: -(-2) is equivalent to +2. For more info you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic

Comment: Close vote...?? And i don't understand why..!!

Comment: What's going on here?! People are *upvoting* wrong answers, *downvoting* the right answers.

Comment: It would be easy to asume that using `=+` is a mistake really wanting to use `+=`. Maybe that's why the downvotes.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029174

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825840

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313423

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151388

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129137

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946938 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874179

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839006

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034848

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442916

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9955885

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967066

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939023

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543669

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754582

:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int i =+ 2;
```

It is positive 2(+2) assignment to variable i. It is more miningful or understandable if your write like   -- `int i = +2;`

One more example -

```
int i = 2;
i=+3;
System.out.println(i);
```

It prints 3.

> `+`      Unary plus operator; indicates 
>           positive value (numbers are 
>           positive without this, however)

More example - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/UnaryDemo.java

Comment: Thanks for editing Suresh :)

Comment: Yes you are right Gokul

Comment: Any comment for downvoting

Answer (score 5):

Upon saying:

```
int i =+ 2;
```

`+` acts as a [unary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

To elaborate, it sets `i` to a positive value `2`.

EDIT: Your update says:

```
int i =- -2;
```

produces 2.  Why?

In this case, it implies that `i=-(-(2))`.  Note that using a unary minus operator might produce *unexpected* results when the value is, say, `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting i equal to +2, which is what you got. What kind of output are you expecting?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted for a correct answer? Do I really need to explain that +2 means positive 2?

Comment: The answer needs much more detail to properly be, well, an answer.

Comment: "What kind of output are you expecting" is literally toxic.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you mean by =+ is really +=.

Your code is assigning the value of +2 (positive 2) to the integer.

For example:

```
int x =+ 4;
x =+ 8;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Will print "8", not 12.  This is because you are assigning x to +4 and then +8.

If you are asking about what += does, it is a shorthand to takes the initial variable and add to it.

```
x += 8
```

is the same as

```
x = x + 8
```

By changing the previous example form =+ to += give us:

```
int x = 4;
x += 8;
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
Console.ReadLine();
```

Will print "12".

Comment: Why the down vote?  Answers original question, as well as an explanation of what looks to be a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the following image for unary operators.

[image]

Here is an exmaple to understand it.

```
public class UnaryDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 10;
        int y = 20;

        int result = +x;

        System.out.println("+x = " + result);

        result = -y;

        System.out.println("-y = " + result);
        }
    }
```

and the output is

```
+x = 10
-y = -20
```

So think the operator as `variable = +value` rather than `variable =+ values`. yeah That space makes it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

As all others are answered, I want to give the JLS reference.
Answer to your Edit

```
int i =- -2;
```

As specified in [jls](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4)

- Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on the operand.
- The type of the unary minus expression is the promoted type of the operand.
- **At run time, the value of the unary minus expression is the arithmetic negation of the promoted value of the operand.**

So,

```
System.out.println(i); //prints 2
```

For integer values, negation is the same as subtraction from zero.

---

**Note**

For floating-point values, negation is not the same as subtraction from zero, because if x is +0.0, then 0.0-x is +0.0, but -x is -0.0.

Unary minus merely inverts the sign of a floating-point number. Special cases of interest:

- If the operand is NaN, the result is NaN. (Recall that NaN has no sign (§4.2.3).)
- If the operand is an infinity, the result is the infinity of opposite sign.
- If the operand is a zero, the result is the zero of opposite sign.

Useful links

1. [unary operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)
2. [Unary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)